# Lock a range of cells in row based on first cell in row for every row in a table

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you in advance for your help.

The short version:

- Need to have it so specific cells in a table are locked based on the what the first cell in that row contains.
- The cell that is used to determine if other cells in the row are locked needs to always remain unlocked

I am working on an Excel sheet that contains a table. This table is used to record key information about products and is being updated daily. Each product is defined in its own row with columns being used to show details such as "Drawing number" and "Customer" etc.
Depending on the stage the product is at in development and how well the product went once completed, it will be labeled with a single "state" from a list such as "Ongoing", "Bad-product", "Archived" etc.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8E5Q.png)
In each cell in each row, the text the cell contains is determined through either data validation in the form of lists or manually typed in. for example, all cells in the customer column will use a dropdown menu to select a customer from a list, but the cells in the drawing number column are always one of a kind so require manual input.

As so many people access and edit this table there are issues with mis-clicking and typing which causes data to be overwritten without someone noticing they have done so.
Because of this issue I want to be able to lock specific columns in a row based on what the first cell in the row contains ("State" column).

In the instance that the state column contains the word "archived" I want to lock the entire row from having its contents being changed.

In the case of the word being "Ongoing" I want to lock column AA and AB in that row.

As it is sometimes is necessary to go back and edit information due to a known mistake I would need to have it so the `State` column always remains unlocked whatever it contains.

I have attached a redacted Excel sheet that contains my attempt at a coded solution.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rzTp0ur1tpXIY_Wa3cVlcwruJ7Q1rT
The code can also be seen below.
Note: I was not sure how to even go about fulfilling the requirement for the "Ongoing" condition so would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction

```
Sub Locking()

Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A3:A612")

For Each cell In Range("A3:A612")

    If cell.Value = "Archived" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Locked = True


    ElseIf cell.Value = "Ongoing" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Locked = False


    ElseIf cell.Value = "Bad" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Locked = False

    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

This is my first post on here as I could not find the solution from looking at several different stack overflow questions. I also watched numerous videos on VBA code, but am definitely missing something, and am struggling to figure out what it is.

If I have posted this incorrectly or extra detail would be helpful, please let me know.

Any and all help is extremely appreciated!

Thank you

Edit: Code works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of locking the entire row

```
 cell.EntireRow.Locked = False
```

if you just want to lock AA and AB in that row do the following:

```
 cell.EntireRow.Locked = False 'unlock entire row first
 'then lock just the 2 rows
 Range("AA" & cell.Row & ":AB" & cell.Row).Locked = True
```

The others would work the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
So I tried to apply the code to the "Ongoing" section but didn't have any luck.
When for example I change A5 to Ongoing I am still able to edit relative cells AA and AB.
I have the code on this specific sheet so that the locking cells sub is called whenever there is a sheet change, but it doesn't seem to run the sub.
I have included a link to a text file that contains the code I am using:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ocvhpLQ5fmVNnjs0d-rM-xliVAGLCxGa

Comment: You have to protect your worksheet. After you protect your worksheet with a password all cells with `.Locked = True` will be locked. If you don't protect the sheet nothing happens.

Comment: @Samoknight If this answer solved your question please mark it as solution.

Comment: Dear @PEH, Is there a method to lock a cell or set of cells or Range of Cells at irregular intervals that can be locked without using Macro routines?

Comment: @Raky You can lock cells manually in the Menu. Or by VBA code. There are no other options in Excel. I suggest to write a new question for that instead of a comment. And describe what you actually want to achive. There might be other solutions to your problem if you can describe the full background of what you try to do.